# Rails 3.1 Deny editing other users images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a web app which uses Devise for authentication. It is a site which allows the user to upload images so the url would be `/images/2`. There is a separate image controller.

I have found that a user could edit an image they didn't upload by changing then URL, e.g. `/images/4/edit`. Is there a way to block them from editing other users images and only allowing them to edit their own?

The images controller, model, etc was created using `rails g scaffold` if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many different solutions for this, but the simplest is when running edit/update/destroy load the image from the current user instead of from all images:

```
def edit
  @image = current_user.images.find( params[:id] )
end

def update
  @image = current_user.images.find( params[:id] )
  # do whatever has to be done
end

def destroy
  @image = current_user.images.find( params[:id] )
  # do whatever has to be done
end
```

Also, using scaffolds is a really bad practice, you should just write our own code, it's simpler, more productive and will lead you to understand how the framework is supposed to work.

You could also use nested controllers for this, but you would have to research a bit to understand how they work and why they might be a better solution.